# Error when trying ggslackr in R

Tags: r, slack-api

I am using `slackr` package to load ggplot images to slack.

I am switching from one server to another server and getting a strange error when using `ggslackr()` function. I am not getting this error when running the same code on the previous server.

`Error: Each variable must have a unique name. Problem variables: ‘real_name’`

Session Information:

```
sessionInfo()  
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)  
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)  
Running under: Gentoo/Linux

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] slackr_1.4.1       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 scales_0.4.0       ggplot2_2.1.0      foreach_1.4.3      RSclient_0.7-3    
[7] data.table_1.9.7  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5      codetools_0.2-14 assertthat_0.1   dplyr_0.5.0      grid_3.3.0       plyr_1.8.4       R6_2.1.2        
 [8] jsonlite_1.0     DBI_0.4-1        gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     httr_1.2.1       iterators_1.0.8  tools_3.3.0     
[15] munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.2-6 tibble_1.1    `
```

Comment: Can you mock up some data for a reproducible example? I'm on a few Slack groups and can try this on them. I'll also link to this SO post in an issue.

Comment: I put something together on your git issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem in the function named slackr_ims (in slackr_utils.R), the last line (line 117) is something like

```
dplyr::left_join( %some stuff% )
```

That throws the errors due some column naming issues that must have changed in the interim.  If you replace this line with

```
suppressWarnings( merge(users, ims, by.x="id", by.y='user') )
```

It will be OK after you build/install the package.

Comment: I found this little bit of code to be quite helpful:

Comment: @rodney-j-dyer, are there any suggested practices to doing this fix?  IN other words, most of the time I'm just install.packages() from cran, how would one intervene here?  Download from source, then change it? then install?